# Cucumber with Capybara gets blank pages only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber, capybara

I'm testing rails app with the Cucumber and Capybara/rack_test.
I have following step definition:

```
Then /^I should see '([^']*)'$/ do |content|
  visit about_path
  response.should have_content(content)
end
```

where `about_path` maps to `/about`.

Every time my story fails with the message

```
Feature: Some Great Feature

  So that I can blah-blah
  As a Blah-blah
  I want blah-blah

  Scenario: Show project label on about page # features/about.feature:7
    Given I'm on '/about' page               # features/step_definitions/about_steps.rb:1
    Then I should see 'About'            # features/step_definitions/about_steps.rb:5
      expected there to be content "About" in "" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/about_steps.rb:7:in `/^I should see '([^']*)'$/'
      features/about.feature:9:in `Then I should see 'About''

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/about.feature:7 # Scenario: Show project label on about page

1 scenario (1 failed)
2 steps (1 failed, 1 passed)
```

Note that actual content is empty. It is empty with every path I've tried.

It is strange because rspecs passes.

Is there anything I could try? Tell me if you need additional information.

Comment: Does it work correctly in a browser?

Comment: Yes, when I run test server I can navigate to http://localhost/about and see the correct page.

Comment: How about debugging it with save_and_open_page?

Comment: @fkreusch, I've inserted `save_and_open_page` just after `visit`, browser shows page without styling, but it definitely not empty.

Comment: Than it seems like a problem with the matcher/content you are passing in. Can you paste the block of the actual html that you expect to match and the value you are trying to match against?

Comment: What versions of cucumber and capybara are you using? What version of rails are you testing against?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `response` to get to the content. Try with `page` instead.